# Simplify creation of a delegate by passing a method?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, encapsulation, object-oriented-analysis

Is there some way to simplify the creation of a delegate for easier read coding?  Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do and I was wondering if there's a way to do it:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(Object sender, EventArgs e);

public class ClassWithEvent
{
    public event MyDelegate MyEvent;

    public ClassWithEvent() { }

    public void RegisterForEvent(Method)
    {
        MyEvent += new MyDelegate(Method);
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, null);
        }
    }

}

public class ClassToRegister
{
    public ClassWithEvent MyEventClass = new ClassWithEvent();

    public ClassToRegister() { }

    public void RegisterMe()
    {
        MyEventClass.RegisterForEvent(MyEventMethod);

        MyEventClass.Trigger();
    }

    public void MyEventMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Writeline("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

The point behind trying to attempt this is in the interest of encapsulation.  I'm assuming that the class which fires the event is essentially a black box to classes accessing it.  As this would be the most preferable Object-Oriented flow that I can see, I was wondering if there's a way to do this or if there's simply no way to do it without the registering class having some knowledge of the delegate it must create.

Comment: Is this code what you *want* to work, or code that does work and you want to chage? If the latter, could you provide what you think *should* work?

Comment: This is hypothetical code.  I'm still new to events and delegates so I may have made a mistake here somewhere that has nothing to do with my question.  I'm just wondering if there's a way for one class to simply pass its method without declaring a delegate for that method in its own code.  I.E. - can "ClassToRegister" subscribe to "MyEvent" without having knowledge of the name of "MyDelegate."

Comment: Is a generic Action<object, EventArgs> delegate acceptable?

Comment: Maybe?  I'm not sure how to create generics.  I guess I should be researching that tree.

Comment: This was mostly a stylistic question - I'm not even sure I have a use for what I'm asking which I guess would be to allow one method to subscribe to multiple different classes which may be using different delegates that all fit the (Object sender, EventArgs e) parameters.

Comment: That is a reason to go generic (so they don't all need to know your special delegate name). Does my answer make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the sense that you don't need a named delegate for this to work. Instead, you can use the generic delegate `Action` (`Action<object, EventArgs>` in your case). Action delegates return void, and have parameters matching the generic type argument.

Normally you would just expose the event directly (avoiding the "Register" function) and so wouldn't need to worry about that part of it anyways.

If you used it, your code would look like:

```
public class ClassWithEvent
{
    public event Action<object, EventArgs> MyEvent;

    public ClassWithEvent() { }

    public void RegisterForEvent(Action<object, EventArgs> Method)
    {
        MyEvent += Method;
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, null);
        }
    }

}

public class ClassToRegister
{
    public ClassWithEvent MyEventClass = new ClassWithEvent();

    public ClassToRegister() { }

    public void RegisterMe()
    {
        MyEventClass.RegisterForEvent(MyEventMethod);

        MyEventClass.Trigger();
    }

    public void MyEventMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Writeline("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I had not really figured out how to look this up as I wasn't sure exactly what I was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx    I'm very grateful.

Comment: I felt like the "exposing the event directly" is the one thing in C# that seems to violate its sense of object-oriented structure.  I'm still not sure I'm happy with a generic delegate like that because I'm thinking I still have to declare it in the "ClassToRegister" class - but I was somewhat thinking there's no way to pass a method without making a pointer to "store it in" first anyway.  I'm making an "array of events" with an internal class that will inform subscribers based on subscriber parameters so it's hard to let the subscribing class manage the array itself.

Comment: Yeah, you have to declare the type somewhere! I'd have to disagree about events breaking OOP, you are just getting a auto-list of function pointers to call. The += is basically the "register" function. Just my opinion though. Glad I could be of help!